# English word for "repetitive, boring work"?

Tags: word-request

Is there an English word for "work which is repetitive (and often boring), but which must be done"?

Comment: I can think of some adjectives to describe such a job like _mechanical, or monotonous_ but not a specific noun.

Comment: drudgery, daily grind, graft, grunt work

Comment: A friend often uses the noun _tedium_ for this, but I hate to leave that as an answer, because it's not commonly used. (It does work, though, so I'll leave it as a comment.)

Comment: @J.R. I was thinking tedious as well, but I don't think that's a noun

Comment: @njz2 - You're right, _tedious_ isn't a noun. That's why I said _tedium_. :-)

Comment: >Menial … consisting of or occupied with work requiring little skill, esp domestic duties such as cleaning. ([The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Menial))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Drudgery* is routine or dull work like *domestic drudgery*. *Donkey work* is an informal (British) synonym.

> "The donkey work had been done - the intricate brushing away of thousands of years of dust and soil was a task undertaken by the steady handed experts."

Comment: Interesting. I haven't heard _donkey work_ over here in the US, but it seems to be a close synonym of [_grunt work_](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grunt+work).

Answer (score 7):

There are several possibilities, depending on the occasion and nuance. My favorite basic one for a thing that is "a) repetitive, b) relatively boring, and c) has to be done" is *chore*.

Here is its definition in Macmillan Dictionary:

> **[chore](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/chore)**
>   an ordinary job that must be done regularly
>   *You can go play after you’ve done your chores.*

The word is generally used for *household chores*, but it does get used in a variety of contexts – like in [this news story](http://www.cleburnecounty.us/announcements/?newsID=263) about a retiring judge:

> *At first, the job was a chore, but as he saw how his work could help people caught in terrible situations, it became a mission*.

The word *chore* is also ideal for describing "repetitive" tasks. Chores are by nature things that need to be done on a regular basis, whether it's referring to chores on the farm, or chores around the house.

Answer (score 7):

To emphasise that the work is boring and without reward, consider one of:

> **Grunt work:** work that is menial and thankless. *During the summer, I earned money doing grunt work. I did all of the grunt work on the project, but my boss got all of the credit.* [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grunt+work)
>
> **Grind:** to do tedious, laborious, and sometimes menial work. [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grind)

The latter has some nice idioms: *back to the grind* (going back to work after a break or vacation), *daily grind* (a tedious daily routine/job), *grind away [at a job]* (e.g. "he had to grind away for years at redecorating the old mansion"). You sometimes also see *grind work* and *on your grind*.

If you want to emphasise the ongoing physical difficulty of the work, and the exhaustion it can cause, *toil* (which can be used both as noun and verb) would be a good choice. The fact the work is mundane is often implied, but it isn't so explicit.

> **Toil:** hard and continuous work; exhausting labor or effort. [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/work)

To emphasise that the work is continuous and unrelenting, consider *working like a dog* or (a common metaphor) being on the *treadmill* (which particularly hints at how one feels little sense of progress or having "got anywhere").

> **Work like a dog** (UK also **work like a Trojan**): to work very hard. *You can work like a ​dog and still not make ​ends ​meet.*
>    [Cambridge Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/work-like-a-dog)
>
> **Treadmill**: a monotonous routine or set of tasks. [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/treadmill)

Comment: "Drudgery" was the first phrase that came to mind, but all these others (except "working like a Trojan") also suggested themselves. "Grunt work" often, but not always, has a military association.