# A word which means something boring that you can not avoid but have to do it on some time intervals

Tags: word-request

For example, some car owners have to wash their cars every weekend.
I have to sweep the floor every night.
These are the things that can be boring but we can not avoid but have to do it.

Are there are any words that can describe or refer to the above examples?

Comment: Do you mean a word that refers to the task or the work itself or a word that describes an aspect of it? If it's the former, this question should be useful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/86992/english-word-for-repetitive-boring-work

Comment: This is a basic research question answerable with a thesaurus or dictionary search on *boring.*

Comment: @JimReynolds: Not at all. No dictionary or thesaurus I checked gave "chore", "get back to the grind", "donkeywork", or "drudgery" as any kind of synonym or related word. If half the answers given, including the accepted answer, could only be given here, that is *by definition* not a dictionary question in the slightest, and voting to close as such does violence to that close reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for a noun, the word **chore** would probably be what you're looking for:

> **chore**
>
> a small job that is done regularly
>
> a dull, unpleasant, or difficult job or experience

Example of usage:

> *The children were each assigned different household chores.*
>
> *Doing taxes can be a real chore.*

Source: [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chore)

Comment: Thumbs up for *chore*.

Answer (score 7):

To draw up such a list of words would be **tedious**.  I would prefer to avoid such **tedium**.  Also, I have to leave in a few minutes and *get back to the grind*.

Answer (score 1):

"monotonous"

Like tedious, but conveys the notion of being more unpleasant and mentally un-stimulating.

> I've been assigned the long monotonous task of mowing the lawn every week.

Answer (score 1):

[*Drudgery*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drudgery) or [*donkeywork*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/donkey-work) might work for you.