# Term for feeling/emotion when you angry because you have to do some tedious work

Tags: word-request

Question:

[A word which means something boring that you can not avoid but have to do it on some time intervals](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89138/a-word-which-means-something-boring-that-you-can-not-avoid-but-have-to-do-it-on)

asked about term for unpleasant unavoidable work and **tedious** is perfect match.

Which word can be used to describe angry feeling because you *should do tedious work* (like single mother takes care of 5 children or pure emigrant works at low paid fast food restaurant and they ask God why they are so unlucky)?

Comment: *Angry* might be just the word. Search online for "synonyms angry". People might feel anger in different ways or intensities. You would need to describe a person's experience in more detail for us to suggest a better word. Also look up *irritated* and *annoyed.* This question is probably not right for our website, because it is too broad, and you should be able to find it on your own. If your research gives you some ideas, and you still have questions, you could change this question, tell us what you found, and what questions you still have.

Comment: *Not looking forward to X* might work if you don't mean angry in the hot-headed yelling screaming sense.

Comment: *ungrateful* might work

Comment: [***'Victim culture'**](http://www.standard.co.uk/news/victim-culture-means-seven-out-of-ten-feel-oppressed-7176112.html) means seven out of ten feel oppressed.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**embittered** : meaning that the person has been made resentful because of the circumstances or their bad luck.

**disgruntled** : also means resentful, discontented or aggrieved because they have been treated unfairly or unjustly.

**grudging (begrudging)** : means an attitude of ill-feeling or resentment resulting from a past insult or injury.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Comment: As opposed to all the explanation and citations in [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/103026/29924), @NathanTuggy?

Comment: @AlanCarmack : In fairness, I added definitions after NT's comment. But the down-votes don't seem justified in comparison with TRomano's answer.

Comment: Well you're behind by 35K points lol. I'm sure Nathan is just trying to help form a good habit in you. TRomano's post should be a comment, though. I haven't downvoted either your answer or any answer here. I'm waiting for the downvotes on mine for the contrarian point of view. The most important part to becoming a key contributor, though, is what Nathan is trying to instill within you. Welcome aboard!

Comment: @AlanCarmack: I was working within review, so TRomano's answer didn't happen to show up at the time. Otherwise I would probably have left a similar comment or perhaps just recommended deletion.

Comment: @NathanTuggy And yet it still sets there  in all its terse, unsupported glory. And no one taking action on it confuses the newbies here, rightly so.

Comment: Do we really need to "support" a word recommendation when the meaning of the word (previously unknown to the non-native speaker) can be looked up in any dictionary? Really?

Comment: +1 for "embittered" or just "bitter". In my opinion, if you are feeling bitter then you are feeling angry + resigned while "indignant" is more like angry + rebellious. So I think the the asker just has to figure out what the secondary emotion is and he'll have a good word for it.

Comment: @TRomano: I would say yes. Often it is instructive to see *why* a given recommendation is appropriate (and why *not*). Single-word answers that would be link-only, but are actually just "links" to a dictionary entry, just aren't very good.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you're going to get anything more tailored than **indignant**:

> adjective: 
>   feeling or showing anger or annoyance at what is perceived as unfair treatment.

Answer (score -1):

**Resentment** would be another possibility.

As in

> Let's see how much resentment one can create by comparing anonymous downvoters to soldier ants. We will judge the aggregate resentment by the negative points ticker.

Comment: @TRomano This is uncharacteristically terse. I'll bet you meant this as a comment.

Comment: I happen to like terse.  Either the word is or isn't apt.

Answer (score -2):

> Which word can be used to describe angry feeling because you should do tedious work (like single mother takes care of 5 children or pure emigrant works at low paid fast food restaurant and they ask God why they are so unlucky)?

***ungrateful***

> Not feeling or showing gratitude

([Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ungrateful).)

Life is about perspective. I guess they could quit work and go live on the street or somewhere worse. Count your blessings. There are always people who have it worse off than you.

Comment: Ungrateful? Are you being sarcastic??

Comment: Sigh. Here we go. Nope, but this is just as good a word as any to cover the situation laid out in the question. Sometimes people should count their blessings and be grateful for each opportunity. Millions of immigrants and thousands of single mothers have done these types of jobs without complaining. And what of the middle class person who sells his soul to a company doing tedious work for 20-30 years? Same difference.

Comment: This is a site to teach people English, not proselytize a political view.  I have no interest in starting a flame war; someone asked for a word that fit their example, not your editorial.

Comment: @noah this is not a political view. it answers the exact question asked, People who are angry about having to do "tediious" work feel ingratitiude.